# App Engine works when access by version specific url, but not by the main url

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

**The Problem:**

I *can* access my Cloud Endpoints API via the following version-specific URL:

```
https://[version]-dot-[myappid].appspot.com/...
```

but I *can't* access it via this main URL:

```
https://[myappid].appspot.com/...
```

the error I receive in the chrome console is this:

```
https://[myappid].appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/userEndpoint/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0 404 (Not found)
```

**What I've done:**

First off let me say I'm very new to App Engine so apologies if this is a silly question.

I've created a Google Cloud Endpoints Backend module as part of my project in Android Studio (v0.5.6) which uses all the new gradle stuff and Objectify annotations.

I've tested my back end locally on the dev server and it all runs fine.

I then deployed it to appengine using the gradle task `appengineUpdate` and all went well.

I deleted previous version instances running in my app engine cloud console and made the newly deployed version (version-2) the default.

I can access and use the endpoint API fine via the version specific URL as described above but not via the main url.

I have a simple index.html file which is using the endpoint via the javascript client library to test with before building client libraries for my android app.

On both versions of the URL the index.html file renders properly, it just can't connect to the API.

If anyone knows how I can get the app to run properly on the main URL (or let me know if it's not supposed to) that would be awesome!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `appengineUpdateAll` which calls both: `appengineUpdate` and `appengineUpdateAllBackends` my bad!